vs2019 Performance Profiler no CPU usage display, All tools are not available.What should I do?
OS: Windows 11 Home 10.0.22631
CPU: Intel i7-13700,2100Mhz
Memory: 48GB
Vsiual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.11.31.
It's a mixed C and C++ project.
When I switch Visual Studio to Chinese, memory usage options is available, when I switch to English, all options are not available.
I need to debug the CPU usage issue, is there any good way to do it?
Performance Profiler Screenshot

It says to choose a target to see the options for that target. A target is a project.

I've updated the screenshot to check the current project. It still only has one tool available, memory usage

This doc says "Only the tools that are applicable to the project type, operating system, and programming language are shown."  I suggest you firstly check if you have installed profiling tools and then check Which tools are supported for my project.

If you create a new project(e.g:c# console app), will the issue persist?

From looking at your screenshot,

Solution configuration is set to Debug.Switch a Release configuration for more accurate results.

Please set the solution configuration to Release, and select Local Windows Debugger (or Local Machine) as the deployment target, then open Performance Profiler to see if  tools are available.
As the document says, "Only the tools that are applicable to the project type, operating system, and programming language are shown. Select Show all tools to also see tools that are disabled for this diagnostic session."
Please  create a new c# or c++ project to check Performance Tools show up.
Docs Referred:
Which tools are supported for my project?
